# Websocket integration in sitecore 9.3

Tags: sitecore-api

We need to integrate the `WebSocket client` into the Sitecore project. We are using controller rendering, but I am not able to understand how to establish duplex communication with a `WebSocket server`. I am able to create a `WebSocket client` in a `console application`, but the same need to be integrated into `Controller rendering`.

I have a requirement to get data from third-party organizations to retrieve data from their WebSocket.
For that I have two options:

1. **Client-Side:** I cannot go with this approach as security concerns.
2. **Server-Side:** For the server Side, I am trying to get the data from WebSocket. For the same, I have written the below logic and invoked it.

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                RunWebSockets().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }

        private static async Task RunWebSockets()
        {
            var client = new ClientWebSocket();
            //wss://echo.websocket.org
            await client.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://*****.execute-api.ap-south-1.****.com/dev"), CancellationToken.None);

            Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

            var sending = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null && line != String.Empty)
                {
                    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line);
                    await client.SendAsync(new ArraySegment(bytes), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
                }

                await client.CloseOutputAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "", CancellationToken.None);
            });

            var receiving = Receiving(client);

            await Task.WhenAll(sending, receiving);
        }

        private static async Task Receiving(ClientWebSocket client)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];

            while (true)
            {
                var result = await client.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

                if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text)
                    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count));

                else if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                {
                    await client.CloseOutputAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "", CancellationToken.None);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

I am not able to establish a connection web socket. Does `Sitecore` provide any `WebSocket` integration?

Comment: I love websockets, but I'm confused what you're trying to achieve.
Do you want your user to establish a websocket connection?
Is the amazonaws endpoint a protected endpoint?
Have you thought about proxying it with SignalR?

Comment: I am getting issue in establishing Web Socket connection. No, it's not aws endpoint.

Comment: in iis did you enable option web socket protocol ?

Comment: @Avinash J Yes, it is enabled in IIS